# SASS width percentage in @for loop

Tags: sass, percentage

I have another question I can't seem to get answered anywhere.

Currently working with a team that needs custom classes to style their elements. They wanted a width percentage class they can put on anything to make something a certain percentage width.

I made this:

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
    .width-percentage-#{$i} {
        width: #{$i}% !important;
    }
}
```

But IntelliJ is throwing an error..

Comment: What is the error message of IntelliJ?

Comment: It gives it a red crinkly line and if I put it in Sassmeister it says: Expected expression.
  stdin 4:11  root stylesheet on line 4 at column 11

Comment: However, it does compile & also work.. .width-percentage-80 for example gives the element an 80% width.. Weird..IntelliJ just doesn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get this error by using DartSass. The following error should be shown:

> Undefined operation "0 % !important".

I suppose DartSass try to use the `%` as [math operator](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-8) modulo which is not possible because `!important` isn't a number (and `$i` is interpolated). You need to interpolate the `%` too (`#{"%"}`):

```
@for $i from 0 through 100 {
    .width-percentage-#{$i} {
        width: #{$i}#{"%"} !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank @sebastian, i tried 10 combinations ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
width: #{$i * 1%} !important;
```